# How do I solve $(y')^2-yy'=e^x$

Tags: differential

I tried taking the derivative wrt x but it did not help. I searched other methods but I could not find a similar question to this. Thanks in advance.

How to solve the equation :

$$(y')^2-yy'=e^x$$

Comment: Do you mean $dy/dx$? Is $p$ a constant?

Comment: yes p equals dy/dx

Comment: Please edit that into the question. That notation is not universal.

Comment: Actually on the LHS, do you mean $(y')^2$ or $y''$?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja how do i find it

Comment: @gt6989b it is (y')^2

Comment: @AhmetSaidÇelik posted the solution

Comment: Does it come from an application?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I solved it:

$$
\begin{align}
\\
0&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)\right]-e^{x}\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)\right]-\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)+\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-\frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)\\
\\
&=\left(2\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)\left(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\\
\\
\end{align}
$$

We get two ODEs:

$$
\begin{align}
\\
0&=\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\\
0&=2\frac{dy}{dx}-y\\
\\
\end{align}
$$

These are normal ODEs and the solutions (after substitution to the original equation) are:

$$
\begin{align}
\\
y&=Ce^{x}-\frac{1}{C}\\
\\
y&=\pm 2i\cdot e^{x/2}\\
\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thank you, i found something similar

Comment: @Milten thank you mate, corrected it

Answer (score 2):

We can factor the DE as $y'(y-y')=e^x$, and then using the integrating factor $e^{-x}$ we can "factor" the DE further as $y'(e^{-x}y)'=1$. There is an obvious asymmetry between the terms being multiplied, which can be *made* symmetric using the substitution $y:=e^{x/2}v$; if you substitute that into the DE, use product rule, difference of squares, and cancel $e^{\pm x/2}$s, you can get a nice separable equation in $v$.